# Shopify ThemeKit is not working on windows 10 environment

Tags: shopify

I have installed Shopify ThemeKit on my windows machine.
After installing ThemeKit, I ran the following command to confirm whether it is installed correctly or not.

```
 theme version
```

Following are the results.

[image]

Then I have tried the following command in Command prompt to generate a config.yml file

```
 theme configure --password=2f012ad145dd5642e85ab4466bd654b1 --store=urflavor.myshopify.com --themeid=41114009658
```

No error or success message has shown on screen after running above command.  See below screenshot

[image]

After this, I have tried manual way to create a config.yml file and fetch files from Shopify. I have created a file config.yml and put following contents into the file

`development:
   password:[PASSWORD HERE]
   store: urflavor.myshopify.com
   theme_id:[THEME ID HERE]`

Then I cd into the folder and tried the following command:

```
 theme download
```

Following are the message on screen:

[image]

Now I went back to the same folder, and sadly it is blank (See below Image)
[image]

I have tried both manual and PowerShell method to install Shopify ThemeKit and I am having same error/issues both times.

**Environment Details**

OS: Windows 10
Themekit : 0.7.5 windows/amd64

Comment: Did you try to download another theme and did you try to run CMD as addministrator? This theme with 15 files looks very suspicious, it might be the theme itself having strange file extensions that are not supported or something in those lines that breaks the download process. I use themekit on win7, win8 and win10, no problems what so over.

Comment: Yes, I have tried running CMD as administrator as well. I have also tried downloading debut theme and I have the same issue with the debut theme as well.

Comment: i have also tried running command `theme bootstrap --password=[your-api-password] --store=[your-store.myshopify.com] --name=testtheme` and a testtheme has been created in my Shopify store admin. I have also tried downloading the same testtheme but no luck.

Comment: Does your private APP have  the correct permissions `Theme templates and theme assets` should be set to `read and write`?

Comment: Yes app have Read and Write permisisons

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching and following different posts on StackOverflow, I didn't find a better solution. I tried same steps on another machine and everything was working fine..

Now on my earlier machine, I found that my Antivirus was the main cause. I have disabled my anti-virus and now ThemeKit is working fine.

Thank you, everyone, who helped me with this.